# Switch javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

Im having trouble with a switch case statement, I've tried using if else too with no luck,

In my HTML I have

```
<select onBlur="functionCalc()" id="art">
<option value="hours" id="hours">Hours</option>
<option value="minutes" id="mins">Minutes</option>
<option value="seconds" id="secs">Seconds</option>
</select>
```

and the js in relation to this is

```
// Workout if Average render time is in minutes seconds etc...
switch(art)
{
case minutes:
    document.write("Finally Friday"); return false;
    break;
case seconds:
    document.write("Finally seconds"); return false;
    break;
default:
    document.write("Finally mins"); return false;
}
```

Comment: what is the complete even handler code? where does `art`, `minutes` and `seconds` come from?

Comment: What trouble are you having with this? You didn't say. Please read this: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 1):

Well hard to tell with the little code you gave, but if I had to guess you are not making string constants, so you were looking at the values of unused variables.

```
// Workout if Average render time is in minutes seconds etc...
switch(art)
{
case "minutes":
    document.write("Finally Friday"); return false;
    break;
case "seconds":
    document.write("Finally seconds"); return false;
    break;
default:
    document.write("Finally mins"); return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't see how you are setting the variable `art` so we can't make any suggestions there…

… unless you are assuming that `art` will be a global variable that references the current value of the form control with the same id (which it won't). You'd need do do something like: `<select onBlur="functionCalc(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)"` and `function functionCalc(art) { … }` instead.

You can't use `document.write` in response to an event though. By the time the event fires, the document will have closed, so you'll automatically call `document.open` and wipe out all the existing content. [Use DOM methods](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/creating-and-modifying-html/) instead.

As @Hogan points out, you probably also need to explicitly make your case statements use strings too.

Comment: Sorry, my variables are being defined in the same page        // Hours Minutes Seconds variables
 var hours = 'hours';
 var minutes = 'minutes';
 var seconds = 'seconds';
 var avgframerndrtme = 6;

Comment: That comment seems like a reasonable response to @Hogan's answer, but has nothing to do with anything I said (except for my edit referencing said other answer which didn't exist when you made the comment).

Comment: Sorry Quentin, I haven't defined an id for ART yet, sorry to sound naive, still learning this but does a switch statement reload the page? in theat case I think I need to use if else statements?

Comment: You have defined an id for it `<select onBlur="functionCalc()" id="art">`, but not a variable.

Comment: A `switch` statement does not reload the page. A `document.write` will trash the page if it runs after the page has finished loading.

Comment: Sorry i meant a variable not id, why would I need to define this however? Thanks

Comment: Because `undefined` isn't going to match any string.